# Z3: Should I use Arrays, IntVectors, or something else?

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

I am wondering what datatype I should be using for my z3 application.  My understanding is that the only options for integer-array-like data structures are Array(IntSort(), IntSort()) and IntVector().

Reasons I think Arrays are overkill: Each array element is only written once, I'm not doing anything like `Store((Store(X, y, z1)), y, z2)`.  In addition, each array has a predefined length of <= 256 (and each integer in the array is between 0 and 63).

Reasons I think BitVectors won't work: I want to use Int variables to index into the arrays.  For instance, I might have `z = Int('z')`, some clauses constraining z, and then `Or(arr[z] == 2, arr[z + 1] == 2)`.  My understanding after playing around with z3 and reading up is that vectors don't support this.

Is there a way I can get the power of variable-indexing without having to use expensive Array operations?

Answer (score 2):

If you have small arrays of fixed-length with no symbolic index access, then I'd strongly recommend using an `IntVector` (See https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#a7e166f891df8f17fd23290bec963b03c)

Note the important thing here is whether you need access with a symbolic index. (That is, do you always address your array with known constant indices, or do you need the ability to read/write to a symbolically addressed location.) From your description, it appears you always statically know the address, so `IntVector` is your best choice. If addresses can be symbolic, then you have to use good old SMTLib arrays, which are more costly.